# I am passing python objects to a template (using jinja) and it is not working for one template but does for the others

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a list of country objects which have attributes such as name, continent, population, abbreviation, etc, and am simply trying to pass that object to a html template. I have other routes all coded the same which work fine but for some reason the country object is passed as a string, and the list appears to be empty.

```
@app.route('/continents/<continent>/<country>')
def countryView(country, continent):
    countries = []
    for c in countriesWorld:
        if c.continent == continent:
            countries.append(c)
        if c.name == country:
            country = c
    return render_template('countryview.html', country=country,        
countries=countries), 200
```

here is my html/jinja template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div id="countrycontainer">
        <h1>{{ country.name }}</h1>
        <img src="{{ "../static/img/flags/" ~ country.abbreviation ~ ".png" 
}}">
</div>

{% endblock %}}
```

if i use '{{ country }} instead of country name, the name shows up, so clearly it has been passed as a string instead of an object and I Cannot work out why. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's tough to say with exactitude what the issue is, but you got 2 things to pay closer attention to: 1. `countriesWorld` may be empty, which means that the value of `country` is never changed. Or 2. `if c.name == country` never becomes `True`, which also means that the value of `country` never changes. Try printing `c.name` and `country` to make sure that they actually match.

Comment: thanks for the response. countriesWorld is a list of country objects and is passed to other routes with no problem, and does not ever get changed. It pulls the info from a csv file when app.py loads so I cant see why it would be empty, and on top of this if i just use {{ county }} instead of {{ country.name }} in my template, then the country name does show.

Comment: The country name shows because it's already been defined. You see, the function `countryView` has an argument called `country`. It is that country that is being passed to your template. So, again check to make sure that `c.name == country` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: So in the csv file the names of countries had a trailing space character which is why the c.name==country was evaluating to false. thanks a lot for your help it works fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trailing space is what caused the problems,  country == c.name never evaluated to true because of this trailing space, and as such the original variable 'country' which was a string, was passed to the view.